# selenium chrome python "InvalidArgumentException" specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, invalidargumentexception

[Leo's question on 8/16/2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531032/how-do-i-specify-a-unique-value-for-user-data-dir) was marked duplicate, yet was not!  I too get the error

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir

I've tried various forms of options and chrome_options with no change.  I tried with and without specifying the use-data-dir, which then just brings up a generic profile.

[DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb) reported

> This question already has an answer here:
>
> [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python)
>
> [How to open a Chrome Profile through --user-data-dir argument of Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium)
>
> [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3)

However, these only show how to use selenium, which I am pretty sure Leo and I have written in the code, yet still get this error.  Help!

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

CrOptions = Options()
ProfilePath = "C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\"
CrOptions.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + ProfilePath)
ProfileName = "Profile 3"
CrOptions.add_argument("profile-directory=" + ProfileName)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=CrOptions)

browser.get("HTTP://msftconnectiontest.com/redirect")
```

It opens up the correct profile in Chrome, but meanwhile gives the InvalidArgumentException and the get command returns:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable

Comment: So which error are you seeing exactly `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use` or `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable`

Comment: hi, You have solved this problem? This problem happens because the previous testcase has opened a chrome browser which is not closed yet.